# If else function with NaN values

Tags: python, if-statement, nan

I imported an excel and now I need multiply certain values from the list but if the value from the first column is NaN, Python should take another column for the calculation. I got the following Code:

```
if pd['Column1'] == 'NaN':
    pd['Column2'] * pd['Column3']
else:
    pd['Column1'] * pd['Column3']
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use `df.isna()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isna()` together with `any()` or `all()`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generating test data assuming all the values in Col1 are 'NaN'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'Col2':[1,2,3,4], 'Col3':[2,3,4,5]}) 

if df['Col1'].isna().all(): # you can also use 'any()' instead of all()
    df['Col4'] = df['Col2']*df['Col3']
else:
   df['Col4'] = df['Col1']*df['Col3']

print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0   NaN     1     2     2
1   NaN     2     3     6
2   NaN     3     4    12
3   NaN     4     5    20
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting/up-voting the answer if helped you.

Comment: As a matter of interest. What would I need to change if not all values in Col1 are NaN. just change from .all() to .any() ? Thank you

Comment: yes. you are right! good work !! Also, it would nice if you could upvote my  previous  main answer. It just a tradition in stackoverflow. [what if someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Just did. Thank you for your great support.

Comment: No problem. Good luck !! happy coding.

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't solve my problem yet. I tried it again and it doesn't work because not all values inside Col1 are NaN. Some have values other doesn't and if it does have a value then take the Value from Col1 otherwise take the value from Col2. Thank you for your help.